# html input onload does not work

Tags: javascript, html, input

How can I do something each time html input element is showing in the html page?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                alert("input is loaded");
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body >
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <input type="text" onload="myFunction()"/> 
    </body>

</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/amj5w7y1/2/

Comment: Explain Your Question  Clearly